# Finding location of char in the alphabet

Tags: java, char, int

If I have a char, for example:

```
 char letter = 'g'
```

is there a way for me to find out where in the alphabet this letter is? (assuming it is in the alphabet)
So for clarification, the answer for letter would be 7, since g is the 7'th letter in the alphabet.

Comment: cast to int and subtract (int)'a'

Comment: Case sensitive or not?

Comment: use `letter - 'a' + 1` (This will return you a number between 1 and 26, but will work only with lowercase)

Comment: Not case sensitive, so thank you, these answered my question.

Comment: I'm blown away by the creativity in some of the answers below.  I want to vote all of you up!

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you can always get the ASCII `int` value for a character in Java by simply casting that character to an `int` as follows:

```
char letter = 'g';
int ascii = (int) letter; # ascii = 103
```

To get the 1-based position in the alphabet, you can offset this value keeping in mind that character `a` has a value of 97:

```
int getPosition(char input) {
  char smalla = 'a';
  int alphabetStart = (int) smalla; # alphabetStart = 97
  int position = (int) input - alphabetStart + 1;
  return position;
}
```

Keep in mind that I have only considered **lowercase** letters of the alphabet in my solution.  Uppercase characters have ASCII values which run from 65 (A) to 90 (Z), and the solution to take those into account would be a bit more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Use **indexOf()** to get position of character from abcdefg... string

Here is the simple solution.

```
public static int getCharPosition(char c)
{
    String line = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    int position = line.indexOf(String.valueOf(c).toLowerCase())+1;
    return position;
}
```

> **Input :** z
>
> **Output :** 26

Answer (score 1):

As being said in the comments, the easiest way to find index of a char is:

```
c.toLowerCase() -  'a' + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [ASCII table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart) each letter has an ordinal number. You can get the ordinal number of a `char` by casting it to `int`.

The lower case letter `a` has an ordinal number of 97, so you have to substract it from your letter's ordinal number. Since the ASCII table starts at ordinal number 0, substract an additional 1.

Java code:

```
char letter = 'g';
int asciiNumber = (int)letter; // 103
final int offset = 97 - 1; // 97 is ASCII code for 'a', -1 since ASCII table starts at 0

int numberInAlphabet = asciiNumber - offset;

System.out.println("Position of letter '" + letter + "': " + numberInAlphabet);
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle both lowercase and uppercase you can do something like this :

```
public int alphabetPosition(char c) {
        int a='a';
        int position=(String.valueOf(c).toLowerCase().codePointAt(0))-a+1;
        return position;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SearchAlphabet {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        char letter='d';
        int ascii=97; //ascii value of a
        int counter=1;
        for(int a=0;a<=27;a++)
        {
            if(ascii==(int)letter)
            {
                System.out.println("Position");
                System.out.println(counter);
                break;
            }
            ascii++;
            counter++;
        }


    }
}
```

Here,we start counter from 1 and incremented by 1 on every iteration after matching the given character ascii.And after matching the with concern character, we print the counter value.